# JS использование одного и того же объекта многоразово

Tags: javascript

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в это примере используется один и тот же самый объект, новый не создается?

```
var OneInstance = function(numberAdd) {
        if(this.numbers === undefined) this.numbers = [];
        this.numbers.push(numberAdd);
        this.showNumbers = function() {
            alert(this.numbers);
        }
        return this;
    }
    OneInstance(1).showNumbers();
    OneInstance(1).showNumbers();
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/55uzxk5v/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, объект `this` тот же самый - `window`:

```js
var OneInstance = function(numberAdd) {
  if (this.numbers === undefined) 
    this.numbers = [];
  this.numbers.push(numberAdd);
  this.showNumbers = function() {
    console.log(this.numbers);
  }
  return this;
}
OneInstance(1).showNumbers();
OneInstance(2).showNumbers();
window.showNumbers();
```

P.S. - объясните, чего Вы хотите. Впечатление таково, что у Вас где-то пропущен оператор `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Если функция вызвана в глобальной области видимости, то `this` означает ссылку на объект браузера `window` То есть контекстным объектом является объект `window`.

При первом вызове функции объекту `window` добавляется свойство `numbers`

```
if(this.numbers === undefined) this.numbers = [];
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

А также при каждом вызове опредяляется свойство windows `showNumbers`

```
    this.showNumbers = function() {
        console.log(this.numbers);
    }
```

В этих вызовах

```
OneInstance(1).showNumbers();
OneInstance(2).showNumbers();
```

так как функция `OneInstance` возвращает `this`, то возвращается ссылка на объект `window`, и вызывается его свойство `showNumbers`

Вы могли бы вызвать эту функцию в контексте произвольного объекта, добавив эту функцию в качестве свойства объекта, и тогда при ее вызове в контексте этого объекта `this` означал бы этот объект.

Comment: "Если функция вызвана в глобальной области видимости," - мне кажется, это надо убрать или поменять на "без указания контекста".

Comment: @Igor Первая же фраза дает разъяснение.

Comment: я имел в виду, что упор должен быть не на "где", а на "как".

Comment: @Igor Здесь имеет место и то, и другое, так как функция могла быть определена внутри другой функции, которая вызвана в контексте некоторого объекта.

Comment: @Igor, либо вообще это стрелочная функция либо объект-обертка вернутая bind

Comment: `this` внутри функции не зависит от того, где она определена - или я чего-то не понимаю :).

Comment: @Igor Зависит о того, где она вызвана и как вызвана.

Comment: @Igor Функция определена в глобальной области видимости и при этом использует this. Значение this не будет определена до тех пор, пока функция не будет вызвана. Она могла бы быть определена как. например, метод объекта.

Comment: Какая разница, где определена функция? Она могла быть определена внутри другой функции, и это ничего бы не изменило.

Comment: @Igor Разве не имеет значение, если функция задается как свойство объекта?

Comment: конечно, но только если она и вызывается - `объект.метод()`